# EF6 with SQL Server CE 4.0, Code-First, check for valid Database-File

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I´m using EF6 with an SQL Server Compact database, Code-First approach and MigrateToLatestVersion-Initializers. I also have two DbContext-derived classes which use the same database. Programming language is C#, IDE is Visual Studio 2013.

On application startup, I want to check wether a given database-file is valid or not. First I check if the file exists, but then I also would like to check if the file is a valid database.

My first approach was to create an instance of each of my DbContext-classes. But as this doesn´t access the Database, I can´t catch any exceptions that would imply an invalid file.

But also when i call a function that accesses the Database, like `SomeContextEntities.ToList()`, I Don´t get any exceptions, even if the file I check is a simple text-document. I guess the Initializer simply overwrites the invalid text-file and creates a new database.

Then I tried `SomeContext.Database.Connection.Open()`, hoping that method would throw an exception when the database-file is invalid, but it doesn´t and the ConnectionState simply changes to "open". As a matter of fact, when I call `SomeContext.Database.Connection.Close()`, the formerly text-file has been transformed into an empty database-file.

Also `SomeContext.Database.Exists()` apparently just checks for file-existance.

Is there a (preferably low-cost) way to check for a valid database-file?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "valid database file" - if you can do .Open() it is valid...

Comment: by 'valid database file' I mean a valid *.sdf-file or in other words: an existing database. If i create e textfile, then rename the suffix to .sdf, set the Connection String to that file and then use Database.Connection.Open(), the textfile is transformed into an empty database-file, without any exceptions thrown I could react to. So I have no chance to let the user know that he´s trying to read an invalid database-file, in this case a text-file.